# How to prevent user from dragging a control added to a user control container at design time

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, user-controls

We want to create a usercontrol as container for maintain button status and arrange button location called **ucSwitchButtonList**.

This usercontrol added only one FlowLayoutControl.

After compiling, you can add ucSwitchButtonList on the form and successfully add buttons from CollectionEditor.

[image: ucSwitchButtonList on the form]

We can modify button objects added in **ucSwitchButtonList** and set properties at design time.

But, when we drag any button at design time, Visual Studio throws a **NullReferenceException** exception.

How to prevent user from dragging buttons in **ucSwitchButtonList** at design time? Or how to handle drag event at design time?

I want to achieve the effect of TabPage in TabControl, which can be selected but not dragged at design time.

[image: exception message]

[image]

ucSwitchButtonList.Designer.cs:

```
partial class ucSwitchButtonList
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.flpBtnContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // flpBtnContainer
        // 
        this.flpBtnContainer.AutoScroll = true;
        this.flpBtnContainer.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.flpBtnContainer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
        this.flpBtnContainer.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.flpBtnContainer.Name = "flpBtnContainer";
        this.flpBtnContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 91);
        this.flpBtnContainer.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // ucSwitchButtonList
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 12F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.Controls.Add(this.flpBtnContainer);
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("新細明體", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(136)));
        this.Name = "ucSwitchButtonList";
        this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(209, 202);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ucSwitchButtonList_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel flpBtnContainer;
}
```

ucSwitchButtonList.cs:

```
public partial class ucSwitchButtonList : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Button> _ButtonList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Button>();
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))
    ]
    public ObservableCollection<Button> ButtonList
    {
        get => _ButtonList;
    }

    public ucSwitchButtonList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        flpBtnContainer.Padding = new Padding(0);
        flpBtnContainer.Size = this.Size;
        flpBtnContainer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _ButtonList.CollectionChanged += ButtonList_CollectionChanged;
        Size = new Size(80, 160);
    }

    private void ucSwitchButtonList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ButtonList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        flpBtnContainer.SuspendLayout();
        flpBtnContainer.Controls.Clear();
        flpBtnContainer.Controls.AddRange(_ButtonList.ToArray());
        flpBtnContainer.ResumeLayout();

        foreach (Control ctl in flpBtnContainer.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is Button btn)
            {
                btn.Click += Btn_Click;
                if (e.NewItems.Contains(btn))
                {
                    btn.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }

        Invalidate(true);
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (DesignMode && BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
        {
            var rect = Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, 0, 0);
            rect.Width--;
            rect.Height--;
            Color lc = ControlPaint.Dark(Parent.BackColor);
            if (lc == Parent.BackColor) lc = ControlPaint.LightLight(Parent.BackColor);

            using (Pen lp = new Pen(lc))
            {
                lp.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
                lp.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Center;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(lp, rect);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214991/how-to-enable-and-disable-dragging-a-button
You can control set the drag-drop event, and also can play with the property "Allow drop" of the controls.

Comment: @DúverCruz Thanks for the info, but my problem is happening at **Design-Time** not **Run-Time**. ^^ The drag action I want to disable is a button created at design time by the CollectionEditor of the UserControl ucSwitchButtonList.

This is more like a TabPage inside a TabControl, which can be selected but not dragged at design time.

Answer (score 0):

After days of research, I have finally found some solutions to this problem.

**Method 1**:
Create a custom button control by inheriting the ControlDesigner class and overriding the OnMouseDragMove() method, so that it won't throw exception messages when it has no action. Then apply this class to the button control we developed. The sample code is as follows:

```
internal class MyButtonControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    protected override void OnMouseDragMove(int x, int y)
    {
        //base.OnMouseDragMove(x, y);
    }
}
```

```
[Designer(typeof(MyButtonControlDesigner))]
public class MyButton : Button { }
```

Then add the my user control button (MyButton) to the ucSwitchButtonList, and no exception messages will appear thereafter.

**Method 2**:
Simply use the native Designer class directly on MyButton and utilize the default actions.

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ButtonBaseDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public class MyButton : Button { }
```

**Discussion**:
It turns out that the issue stems from the operations triggered by the added control during the design phase, rather than the ucSwitchButtonList object we created. While WinForms is considered an older technology, it is still highly useful. I have also gained a lot of knowledge from this experience.